# Using Lists in Java to store user input and perform tasks

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, set

This is my first time using List for this program. The goal is to avoid using the Set collection interface in Java, but rather the List interface.

I'm currently working on the first part, allowing the user to create a step. However, I'm lost as to how the program will store the integers, and then pull each set (using the names the user makes) to perform operations on them.

I provided the project requirements at the bottom, but I would much prefer to have an understanding of how lists work and how to best implement them in order to perform the correct operations, than an answer to how to do the project.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Set {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1) Create a set /n"
                + "2) Print the list of created sets /n"
                + "3) Print a set /n4) Union /n" + "5) Intersection /n"
                + "6) Subtraction /n" + "7) Exit /n"
                + "Please enter the number of the command you desire >");
        number = scan.nextInt();

        ArrayList<String> setName = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> setNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        if (number == 1) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a name for the set: ");
            setName.add(scan.next());
            System.out
                    .println("Please enter values for the set, separated by a space (To establish end of input: 'X'): ");
            setNumber.add(scan.nextInt());
        }


    }
}
```

"In this project you are going to work with sets. You should write a Java program that
allows users to create sets and perform some simple operations on them, including union,
intersection, and subtraction.
Upon execution, the program should show a menu to the user and prompt the user to
enter a command (a number from the menu). Your menu should look similar to:
1) Create a set.
2) Print the list of created sets
3) Print a set
4) Union
5) Intersection
6) Subtraction
7) Exit
Please enter the number of the command >

After the user inputs a command, your program will perform a specific task. After the task has been completed, your program should print back the menu and
await a new command.

Note:
The sets should only contain integer values.
There should be no limit on the number of sets that users can create and number
of elements in a set.
The user can input any names to access sets or to perform an operation on them.
Your program should always check if the requested set exists.
The program should deal with empty sets, i.e. sets with no elements. For example, to create an empty set, user can enter ‘X’ without providing any integer values.
A set cannot have duplicate values. All elements in a set must be unique.
Your program should never crash.
You must not use Java’s Set from the Collection interfaces for this project.
You should use List (details below)."

Answer (score 1):

You should make a `NumberSet` class which contains 2 class variables:

- `String name`
- `ArrayList<Integer> numbers`

You will also write the methods in the `NumberSet` class:

- `public NumberSet union(NumberSet secondSet)`
- `public NumberSet intersection(NumberSet secondSet)`
- `public NumberSet subtraction(NumberSet secondSet)`
- `public void printSet()`

Make sure the constructor method initializes the `ArrayList<Integer> numbers` else wise you'll get null pointer exceptions.

Then in your `main`, you should have a list of NumberSets `ArrayList<NumberSet> sets`. This will keep track of all user created NumberSets.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1) Create a set /n"
            + "2) Print the list of created sets /n"
            + "3) Print a set /n4) Union /n" + "5) Intersection /n"
            + "6) Subtraction /n" + "7) Exit /n"
            + "Please enter the number of the command you desire >");
    number = scan.nextInt();

    ArrayList<NumberSet> sets = new ArrayList<NumberSet>();

    if (number == 1) {
        NumberSet newSet = new NumberSet();

        System.out.println("Please enter a name for the set: ");
        newSet.name = scan.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter values for the set, separated by a space (To establish end of input: 'X'): ");
        while(scan.hasNextInt()){
            newSet.numbers.add(scan.nextInt());
        }

        sets.add(newSet);
    }
    else if(number == 2){
        //code
    }
    //etc.
}
```